# Typescript require arguments to match type signature of first argument

Tags: typescript, types

I have a Class `A`, which has function `f` (possibly overwritten by subclasses).

I would like to define a function, `g` so that `g(cls, ...args)` would only work if `cls` is a subclass of `A` and `args` matches the type signature of `cls.f`. Is there a way to do this?

Edit: I have changed the above to reflect the fact that the first argument to `g` is actually a *constructor* of a subclass of `A`, rather than an instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can use [tuples in rest/spread types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#tuples-in-rest-parameters-and-spread-expressions) to get this since TS 3.0:

```
declare class A {
  f(...args: any[]): any;
}
declare function g<T extends A>(val: T, ...args: Parameters<T['f']>): void;

declare class B extends A {
  f(x: string, y: number): boolean;
}
declare const b: B;
g(b, "hey", 123); // okay
g(b, 123, "hey"); // error
```

The tuple rest/spread inference is hidden inside the `Parameters` type function defined in the [standard library](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/v3.2.2/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1461-L1464) as:

```
type Parameters<T extends (...args: any[]) => any> = 
  T extends (...args: infer P) => any ? P : never;
```

Is that what you're looking for?

---

EDIT: if `val` is supposed to be a *constructor*, then you could do it like this:

```
declare function g<T extends A>(
  val: new(...args:any[])=>T, 
  ...args: Parameters<T['f']>
): void;

declare class B extends A {
  f(x: string, y: number): boolean;
}
g(B, "hey", 123); // okay
g(B, 123, "hey"); // error
```

Or essentially the same thing:

```
declare function g<T extends new (...args: any[]) => A>(
  val: T,
  ...args: Parameters<InstanceType<T>['f']>
): void;
```

depending on whether you want `T` to be a constructor type or an instance type.

Comment: That actually answered the question perfectly, but I realized I had asked it wrong. Please see the edit.

Comment: This answer may still work in the modified case, but changing T['f'] to T.prototype['f'] perhaps?

Comment: Further, `...args: Parameters<T['f']>` gives the error `A rest parameter must be of an array type`

Comment: Updated to deal with constructor

Comment: Uh, it should not give you such an error.  What version of TS are you using?  [link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=declare%20class%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20f%28...args%3A%20any%5B%5D%29%3A%20any%3B%0A%7D%0Adeclare%20function%20g%3CT%20extends%20A%3E%28val%3A%20T%2C%20...args%3A%20Parameters%3CT%5B%27f%27%5D%3E%29%3A%20void%3B%0A%0Adeclare%20class%20B%20extends%20A%20%7B%0A%20%20f%28x%3A%20string%2C%20y%3A%20number%29%3A%20boolean%3B%0A%7D%0Adeclare%20const%20b%3A%20B%3B%0Ag%28b%2C%20%22hey%22%2C%20123%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20okay%0Ag%28b%2C%20123%2C%20%22hey%22%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20error)

Comment: Yeah your example works on my system too so there must be something else up I haven't figured out. I'll accept your answer, thanks a ton for the help!